# R Barplot: How to arrange x-labels by day of week?

Tags: r, plot, graph, bar-chart

The data below contains 2 columns I want to plot against each other: .
Currently, I can create barplot. But the x-axis is sorted alphabetically.
How do I want arrange the x-labels in the order of week: Monday-Sunday?

```
# Summarize data by date
data$dow = format(data$date, format = "%a")

steps_by_dow <- data %>% 
                group_by(dow) %>% 
                summarize(sum_steps = mean(steps))

# plot histogram for total steps per day
barplot(sum_steps ~ dow, steps_by_dow, xlab = "Daily steps", ylab = "Count (step)", 
     main = "Histogram of the total steps taken per day")
```

[image]

Comment: `steps_by_dow$dow <- factor(steps_by_dow$dow, levels = c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"))` and then plot the `barplot`.

Comment: This works. Thanks! That's a really simple trick.